# Writing a quiz in Python using functions

Tags: python, function

I have written this code to start my quiz program...I am not sure if this is correct code, for some reason the program asks the user to enter number of players twice.  I'm not sure how to use the variables 'numberPlayers' and 'playerNames' outside the function???

```
print('\t\tWelcome to the Quiz...')

print()

def getNumberOfPlayers():
    numberPlayers = int(input('Enter number of players (2-4): '))
    while numberPlayers <2 or numberPlayers >4:
    numberPlayers = int(input('Invalid: Enter number of players (2-4): '))
    print('Thanks, there are', numberPlayers, 'players in the game')
    return numberPlayers

def getNameOfPlayers():
    playerNames=[]
    numberPlayers=getNumberOfPlayers()
    for i in range (numberPlayers):
        names=input('Enter a player name, then press enter: ')
        playerNames.append(names)
    print(playerNames)
    print('Player 1 is', playerNames[0])
    print('Players 2 is', playerNames[1])
    return playerNames


getNumberOfPlayers()
getNameOfPlayers()
```

Comment: Just count how many times you're calling ``getNumberOfPlayers()``. Hint: the correct answer is ``twice``.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that code wont run. Indentation is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the code for you. You were calling the function twice so it ran it twice. Once when you wanted it to in the first function but again in the second function when you wanted to get the number of players again. You can use a global variable for this since the number of players won't change.

```
def getNumberOfPlayers():
    global numberPlayers
    numberPlayers = int(input('Enter number of players (2-4): '))
    if numberPlayers <2 or numberPlayers >4:
        numberPlayers = int(input('Invalid: Enter number of players (2-4): '))
        print('Thanks, there are', numberPlayers, 'players in the game')
        return numberPlayers

def getNameOfPlayers():
    playerNames=[]
    for i in range (numberPlayers):
        names=input('Enter a player name, then press enter: ')
        playerNames.append(names)
    print(playerNames)
    print('Player 1 is', playerNames[0])
    print('Players 2 is', playerNames[1])
    return playerNames


getNumberOfPlayers()
getNameOfPlayers()
```

Comment: That answers my question perfectly...

Comment: @StTebb Then please click the check mark under the 0 for this answer.